# grails nested bean error

Tags: java, grails, javabeans

I have a website in grails that uses an memory database, was working before I made some serious domain class changes.  Any thoughts on this?  Never seen anything like it before.

```
Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource':     Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

**EDIT**

Full Stack Trace

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -  Dgrails.home=/Users/afrieden/grails/grails-1.3.7 -Dbase.dir=/Users/afrieden/GrailsProjects/GRVariantInterface/trunk -Dtools.jar=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=/Users/afrieden/grails/grails-1.3.7/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Didea.launcher.port=7537 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12.app/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/afrieden/grails/grails-1.3.7/lib/groovy-all-1.7.8.jar:/Users/afrieden/grails/grails-1.3.7/dist/grails-bootstrap-1.3.7.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12.app/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf /Users/afrieden/grails/grails-1.3.7/conf/groovy-starter.conf run-app
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /Users/afrieden/grails/grails-1.3.7

Base Directory: /Users/afrieden/GrailsProjects/GRVariantInterface/trunk
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 747ms.
Running script /Users/afrieden/grails/grails-1.3.7/scripts/RunApp.groovy
Environment set to development
[groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/afrieden/GrailsProjects/GRVariantInterface/trunk/target/classes
[delete] Deleting directory /Users/afrieden/.grails/1.3.7/projects/trunk/tomcat
Running Grails application..
2013-02-27 16:04:33,160 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.grails.tomcat.InlineExplodedTomcatServer.doStart(InlineExplodedTomcatServer.groovy:112)
at org.grails.tomcat.InlineExplodedTomcatServer$doStart.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:97)
at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
... 26 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
... 26 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: grvariant.vardb.UserRole(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)
at grvariant.vardb.UserRole.$INIT(UserRole.groovy)
at grvariant.vardb.UserRole.<clinit>(UserRole.groovy)
... 26 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Just looks like session factory creation is hosed for some reason.

Comment: Any fixes for that?  Not too familiar with it

Comment: Do you have anything in your BootStrap.groovy that might be affected by the domain changes, like creating instances of the class? I've seen this when I've either changed a domain class and not updated bootstrap code, or just gorped up a bootstrap line.

Comment: I've deleted everything out in the bootstrap.groovy so it just has init and destroy

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Done, stacktrace has been added

Comment: The problem is related to grvariant.vardb.UserRole, please post the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you used Spring Security plugin, and in UserRole class there is something wrong.

The key error message is:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: 
grvariant.vardb.UserRole(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)
```

My guess is that the 2 Strings and 1 Integer properties does not match the original User and Role references Spring Security wanted, or you added a String property which has some conflict with Grails/MySQL, like using a reserved word as property name.

Posting the definition of this class may be helpful for further discussion.